# Trying to create dynamic copy and replace function using special cells

Tags: excel, vba, replace, copy

I am trying to create a code that will search for a given column header and copy the contents of the column after first replacing all the blanks with a zero.

I have tried using the following code, but the second parameter for the range function at the bottom does not work when I try to use "lastrow".

lastrow is defined by the numeric last row value, but I cant seem to figure out how to combine that with the alphabetical reference that is given in dbt.address

```
`Sub replacezeros()

Dim dbt As Range
Dim lastrow As Range


'This is to define last row of array
Set lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
Debug.Print lastrow.Row


'This is for Debit
Set dbt = Range("A1:J1").Find("Debit")
Debug.Print dbt.Address
Debug.Print dbt.Cells


'Range(dbt.Address,).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = 0


End Sub`
```

Hoping to get this to replace all zeros only in that one column that is searched to select "Debit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I've understood your problem - try this:

```
Sub replacezeros()

Dim dbt As Range
Dim lastrow As Range

'This is to define last row of array
Set lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
Debug.Print lastrow.Row

'This is for Debit
Set dbt = Range("A1:J1").Find("Debit")

If Not dbt Is Nothing Then  'avoid error if Debit not found
    On Error Resume Next    'avoid error if no blanks
    Range(dbt.Offset(1), Cells(lastrow.Row, dbt.Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 0
    On Error GoTo 0
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work... (untested though)

```
Sub replacezeros()
     Dim dbt As Range, rData As Range, Cell As Range
     Dim lastrow As Long: lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

     'This is for Debit
     Set dbt = Range("A1:J1").Find("Debit")
     If Not dbt Is Nothing Then
          Set rData = Range(Cells(1,dbt.Column),Cells(lastrow, dbt.Column))
          For Each Cell In rData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
               Cell.Value = 0
          Next Cell
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Syntax error on the set rData- thank you though, this is very helpful

Comment: This won't work `Cells(lastrow, dbt.Column)` as `lastrow` is (confusingly!) a range, not a row. See my answer.